# With JavaScript how would I increment numbers in an array using a for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to increment the numbers in the array

```
var myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4];
```

I try to use

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
     myArray[i] + 1;
}
```

but that doesn't seem to do anything :( please help

Comment: easiest and simplest way is `myArray.map(i => ++i);`

Answer (score 13):

You can use `map()` which will make it quite clean:

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4];
arr = arr.map(function(val){return ++val;});
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 13):

Use the ES6 arrow function:

```js
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
new_arr = arr.map(a => a+1);
console.log(new_arr);
```

Answer (score 10):

There's many possibilities to do that, you can use plus equal `+=` like following :

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
    myArray[i] += 1;
}
```

Or simply :

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
    myArray[i] = myArray[i] + 1;
}
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
var myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4];

for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
    myArray[i] += 1;
}

alert(myArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your array contains ordered numbers, with increment of size 1, you can also use this code:

```js
var myArray = [1,2,3,4];

myArray.push(myArray[myArray.length - 1] + 1);
myArray.shift();

alert(myArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Without Es6,

```
 myArray[i] =  myArray[i] + 1;
        or
   ++myArray[i]
```

Will work.

Comment: This is not returning the next element in the array, it is increasing the adding 1 to the current element

Answer (score 1):

You can use Array constructor.

Using `Array.map()` method, fill the series with numbers

For Example :

```js
Array(5 + 1).fill().map((_, index) => index + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ES6's `Array.from()` method. The callback is a mapping function, which you can use to add one to each number in the array.

Here the prefix (rather than postfix) increment operator `++` is used in the map function because when you use the increment operator before the operand, the increment occurs *before* the value is returned, whereas with postfix, the original value will be returned before the operand will be increased (so, an unchanged version of the array would be returned in the case of `x++`).

```
function addOne(arr) {
  return Array.from(arr, x => ++x);
}
        
addOne([1, 2, 3]); // [2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr1 = Array.from(Array(5), (_, index) => index);
console.log(arr1); // ️ [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ]

const arr2 = Array.from(Array(5), (_, index) => index + 1);
console.log(arr2); // ️ [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
```

Comment: This creates a new array containing a sequence, it does not increment the values of an existing array, right?

Answer (score 0):

An ES6 functional solution would be:

```js
myArray.forEach((_, i) => myArray[i]++);
// or
myArray.forEach((_, i, a) => a[i]++);
```

This is basically the same as Zakaria Acharki's answer. The arguments passed to the arrow function by [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) are the element themselves, the index and a reference to the array. Since the values are, in this particular situation, numbers, the `_` variable holds a copy of the value, and incrementing `_` won't affect anything outside our function's scope. However, `myArray[i]` or `a[i]` is a reference, which works as expected when we increment it.

Try it:

```js
console.config({ maximize: true });

const myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4];
myArray.forEach((_, i) => myArray[i]++);
console.log(myArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

When [this proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-iterator-helpers) is accepted (currently it is at stage 3) and supported by browsers, you can do something like this:

```js
myArray.keys().forEach(i => myArray[i]++);
```

[`Array#keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/keys) returns an [iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Iterator) that yields the array's keys, which are its numeric indices. `.forEach()` works the same as `Array#forEach()`; the difference between *this example* and *the example above* (not the methods themselves) is that the first argument is now also the index, so we wouldn't need the second one.

Try it (as of May 2023, this doesn't work):

```js
console.config({ maximize: true });

const myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4];
myArray.keys().forEach(i => myArray[i]++);
console.log(myArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can now do this with `Array.reduce()` ([MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)):

```
array = [23,10]
array.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue)
// Returns 33
```