# How to use an Operator (+,-,x,/) to an Array using a for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays

You are given an array of five numbers called increaseByTwo. Use a for loop to iterate through the array and increase each number by two.

const increaseByTwo = [1,2,3,4,5];

I need the result to be [3,4,5,6,7]

I'm not sure how to add +2 to the array itself, or any operator.

I've currently tried

```
const increaseByTwo = [1,2,3,4,5];
for (let i=0, i<increaseByTwo.length, i++)
console.log (increaseByTwo + 2)
```

Results turn out to be but
 3
 4
 5
 6 
 7

on each seperate line, but need it to do be on one [3,4,5,6,7]

Comment: Results don't turn out to be like that.

Comment: how do i modify my results to make it look nice as a list?

Comment: in the console or in the browser? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46141450/create-li-from-loop-through-array-and-display-to-html-as-a-list

Comment: Possible duplicate of [With JavaScript how would I increment numbers in an array using a for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32796230/with-javascript-how-would-i-increment-numbers-in-an-array-using-a-for-loop)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr =  [1,2,3,4,5];
console.log(arr.map((e)=> e + 2))
```

Comment: @JuniorSQL go through this link. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 1):

```
const increaseByTwo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

for (let i = 0; i < increaseByTwo.length; i++){ 

  increaseByTwo[i] = increaseByTwo[i] + 2;     //increaseByTwo[i] += 2;

}

console.log(increaseByTwo);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `.map()` to get the resultant array:

```js
const input = [1,2,3,4,5];

const output = input.map(v => v += 2);

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the `.map()` operator to modify element values. For example,

```
let increaseByTwo = [1,2,3,4,5];
increaseByTwo = increaseByTwo.map(num=>num+2);
console.log(increaseByTwo);
```

Or, if you really want to use a `for` loop, you can use this:

```
let increaseByTwo = [1,2,3,4,5];
for(let i = 0;i<increaseByTwo.length;++i){
  increaseByTwo[i]+=2;
}
console.log(increaseByTwo);
```

This should both work.

Answer (score 0):

`MyArray.map((elt)=>(elt+2));`

This will basically pass each element into the function

`(elt) => elt + 2`

and will apply the result to the element.
You can also do

```
for(var i = 0; i < MyArray.length; i++) {
    MyArray[i] += 2;
}
```

Now, for multiple operations and numbers. If you have something like `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and you want to do the following `[1 + 4, 2 * 6, 3 - 4, 4 / 8, 5 + 6]`

```
var operators = '+*-/+'.split('');
var secondnums = [4,6,4,8,6];
var MyArray = [1,2,3,4,5]; 
for(var i = 0; i < MyArray.length; i++) {
    MyArray[i] = eval(MyArray[i]+operators[i]+secondnums[i]);
}

console.log(MyArray)
// [5, 12, -1, 0.5, 11] AKA [1 + 4, 2 * 6, 3 - 4, 4 / 8, 5 + 6]
```